# Docker: Ignore some files which are needed in build context

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a folder : `/docker` on my project root and it contains certain files like Apache configs which I need to copy to the correct folders during teh build.

```
Project-root
------docker folder
-----------apache.conf
```

Now

```
DOCKERFILE
```

In my dockerfile i have a copy command which copies the whole of root to the container.

```
`Issue`
```

I don't want the `docker` folder to be copied to the built image.

I added `docker` to the `.dockerignore`. But this leads to the problem that these files are not sent to the build context and then the build command fails.

```
WORKAROUND
```

Use the RUN command in the dockerfile to remove the `docker` folder instead of using `.dockerignore`

```
QUESTION
```

Is there any better solution?

```
DOCKER FILe:
FROM <baseimage>
WORKDIR /var/www/html/
COPY . /var/www/html/MYFOLDER
COPY ./docker/apache.conf /etc/httpd/conf/apache.conf
COPY ./docker/sites-enabled /etc/httpd/sites-enabled
```

Comment: Sending files to the build-context doesn't mean that these will be included in the image that you are going to generate. use `COPY` command in Dockerfile to decided which all things matter in the final image.

Comment: @fly2matrix : you mean there is a exclude flag in the COPY command? Can you send me a link for  the same?

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile ?

Comment: @fly2matrix: done

Comment: Take a look at this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747776/copy-with-docker-but-with-exclusion

Comment: @fly2matrix : using a ! before the file name means that the same would be copied using the COPY command.