# Docker npm install --production not working

Tags: docker, npm, dockerfile, npm-install, alpine-linux

I have a dockerfile where I am using alpine-nodejs version 16 as the base image. The npm version is 8.

When the step of `npm install --production` is executed while doing `docker build`, it is also installing dependencies listed under dev-dependencies of package.json, contrary to the use-case of production flag.
I also used `npm install --only=production` but that also doesn't seem to work.

With alpine nodejs version 14, the flag is working as expected and dev-dependencies are not getting installed in container. Is there any issue with alpine node version 16 image? Thanks.

Comment: What would be the expected behavior as opposed to what is actually happening?

Comment: Expectation is that it should not install dependencies mention within devdependencies block in package.json. Whereas currently it is installing both devdependencies as well as dependencies.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?  How do you tell the wrong dependency set is being installed?

Comment: I can confirm the same problem `with node:16.14-stretch-slim` image.

Comment: @Passiday - I have found the root cause of the issue after struggling on it for weeks. Kindly, look for my answer.Hope it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with this for weeks, I have finally found the root cause and it is really dumb of me to not pay attention to that, I don't want others to make the same mistake. Since the code is proprietary, I can't share it. But I will explain the problem.

The image with `nodejs:16` uses `npm` 8.0 whereas the one with `nodejs:14` uses some `npm` version < 8.0.

The difference between them is in version 8.0, `npm` will also install the dependencies listed within `peerDependencies` block. (I am unsure if this behavior started from npm 8.0 or some previous versions)

So, why did I think npm is installing both `devDependencies` as well as `dependencies`?

When I was working with the `nodejs:14` image, I moved certain dependencies from `dependencies` block to `devDependencies` block. So when I upgraded to `nodejs:16`, those dependencies returned.

Actually, the reason they came back because they were being internally used by a transitive dependency, which was listed within `peerDependency` block of `package.json`.

**So, the takehome lesson?**

Make sure the dependency you want to be removed isn't being consumed directly or transitively within `dependency` as well as `peerDependency` block.

Comment: It would be hilarious if express used my types module as peer dependency.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your `Dockerfile` probably has something like `COPY . .` but you don't set `.dockerignore` correctly, e.g. you didn't add `node_modules` to your `.dockerignore` (check [COPY with docker but with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747776/copy-with-docker-but-with-exclusion) for the further information about `.dockerignore`)

I made the same mistake too and it should have nothing do with nodejs14 or nodejs16

BTW, `npm install --only=prod[uction]` is [npm 6.x format](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) and `npm install --production` is [npm 8.x format](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install). One difference is that in npm 8.x if you set `NODE_ENV production` npm 8.x will only install dependencies even if you run `npm install`  but for npm6.x `npm install --only` will ignore NODE_ENV

Answer (score 1):

Starting from NPM 8, the flag to install only production dependencies changed. Instead of specifying which dependencies to install:

```
--only=production
```

We now specify which dependencies to omit:

```
--omit=dev
```

If we're using the latest version of NPM, we'll want to use this new approach each time we run npm install in our Dockerfile. For example, we want to use:

```
RUN npm run install-server --omit=dev
```

Rather than:

```
RUN npm run install-server --only=production
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems that npm ignores --production (or equivalent) flags when `package-lock.json` file is present.