# Docker ignore file for multistage build

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-image, docker-layer, docker-copy

I need to exclude file in Docker COPY for the first stage but use it in another COPY for the second stage, because it breaks docker layer caching.

My folder structure looks like:

```
src/
public/
.env
package.json
nginx.conf
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM node:14 as builder                   # line-1
WORKDIR /app                              # line-2
COPY . /app                               # line-3 nginx.conf is copied but not needed
RUN yarn && yarn build                    # line-4

FROM nginx:1.21.1                         # line-5
WORKDIR /app                              # line-6
COPY --from=builder /app/build /app/build # line-7
COPY nginx.conf /app                      # line-8 nginx.conf is copied

CMD nginx -c /app/nginx.conf              # line-9
```

When I change `nginx.conf` docker layer caching becomes invalidated because of the 3rd line.

I cannot use `.dockerignore` because it will ignore it for both stages.

Obvious solution is to copy all the needed folders one by one, but that seems to be unreliable because project structure can change from time to time and I'd like to avoid extra effort of Dockerfile maintenance & updating.

Is there shorter way to overcome this apart from that is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54725355/4175647)?

Comment: You could change round the folder structure since the outside doesn't need to mirror the inside! Create an external folder like /app with everything in apart from nginx.conf and copy that into container /app then later, also copy nginx.conf from root folder to /app

Comment: @LukeBriner yes, but nginx.conf is just one example among the others and wrapping folder structure may be confusing as well for developers. They often follow guidelines and when creating new app they'd rather stick to `npm init` etc... I do not expect from everyone to fully understand of whatever Docker is. There are also some cases when they need to add namespace to the whole project and that is painful as well

Comment: Then I don't know any other options except expanding the COPY . to be more specific about what you want to copy and when. Lots of people have complained about a lack of pattern matching with the copy commands but if you cannot change the folder structure, you might not have another option.

Comment: @LukeBriner thanks for the response, let there be a question just as for community till the time when this feature will be implemented or for those who may come up with another solution