# Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions

Tags: docker, dockerfile, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to dockerize a frontend app which was created using vite and vue3. It is not working as a container. Here is the error response.

**(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.**

```
VITE v3.2.4  ready in 191 ms

  âžœ  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  âžœ  Network: http://172.17.0.2:5173/
(!) Could not auto-determine entry point from rollupOptions or html files and there are no explicit optimizeDeps.include patterns. Skipping dependency pre-bundling.
```

Dockerfile

```
# base image
FROM node:16.3.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install and cache app dependencies
COPY package.json /app/package.json
RUN npm install
RUN npm install @vue/cli@3.7.0 -g
# start app
CMD ["npm", "run", "dev", "--", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

vite.config.ts

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [vue(), vueJsx()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
        }
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            input: {
                main: resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
            }
        }
    }

})
```

`index.html` exist in the same directory with `vite.config.ts` and `.Dockerfile`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm coming here because i had the same issue with LARAVEL + REACT + vite configuration, issue was i was playing with .js and .jsx, once i corrected that by giving same name as the file, it got resolved.

Comment: Did you inspect your container to see if your files are properly copied? Do you explicitly mount your local files on /app when you launch your container? If not, when do you plan to copy your src files in the container (nowhere found in the dockerfile)?

Comment: @Bigood Can you provide an example of copying command. this is a typcial dockerfile recommended for vue app?

Answer (score 8):

You are probably using the command `yarn dev run` instead of `yarn run dev` to run the dev server

Comment: the command is `npm run dev`. any combination of the command gives an error which is related syntax.

Comment: This answer helped me in the right direction. I was accidentally using `vite run dev`, when I should be using `npm run dev`

Answer (score 4):

This error usually occurs when your css or js files are missing from the specified folder. Like for example in your viteconfig.js file. it always look like this

```
   plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: [
            'resources/css/app.css',
            'resources/js/app.js',
           ],
        refresh: true,
       }),
    ],
```

Confirm if those files are in the right place or if you've moved them to a folder like public then you need to update here to

```
 plugins: [
    laravel({
        input: [
            'public/css/app.css',
            'public/js/app.js',
           ],
        refresh: true,
       }),
    ],
```

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with the same error (blindly following some tutorials), I found that I had to copy all source files to the workdir (in your case `/app`) instead of only `package.json` in the Dockerfile:

```
COPY . /app/
```

Don't forget to add `node_modules` to `.dockerignore` [so they won't be copied](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43747867/3098783).