# I am trying to build a image for my node.js api, but a few problems left in understanding the setence of yml

Tags: node.js, docker, yaml

```
FROM node:18.9.1
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 4000
CMD ["yarn", "start"]
```

There, first question, how to understand the effect of yarn.lock and `yarn install` can't be run sucesssfully without it?

Second, if `yarn install` successfully run, then there will be a filefolder called "node_modules" inside the docker workdir, then `copy . .` will copy the node_modules locally to the workdir of docker, there will be a confilt, if I understand right?

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time; also see [ask] in the SO Help Center.  You should exclude your `node_modules` directory from the Docker build context using a `.dockerignore` file, as in [COPY with docker but with exclusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747776/copy-with-docker-but-with-exclusion).

Answer (score 0):

About the first question, I'm helpless as I'm not aware of it.

About the second one, you should include the node_modules, log (if exists in your app), IDE related folders, Readme files, .git and .gitignore kind of files using

> .dockerignore

file.